# How to display the currency symbol to the right in Angular

Tags: angular, pipe, currency, euro

I have to display Euro currency like this : `583 €`.

But with this code:

```
{{ price | currency:'EUR':true }}
```

I get `€583`, is there any option in Angular core to move the symbol to right? A lot of european countries use the symbol at the right (France, Germany, Spain, Italy).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since Angular2 RC6 version you can set default locale directly in your app module (providers):

```
import {NgModule, LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'de-DE' // 'de-DE' for Germany, 'fr-FR' for France ...
    },
  ]
})
```

Afterwards the currency pipe should pick up the locale settings and move the symbol to right:

```
@Component({
  selector:"my-app",

  template:`
    <h2>Price:<h2>
     {{price|currency:'EUR':true}}
  `
})
```

Comment: If you are using Angular5, in order for this to work you have to import and register your locale first like
`import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
registerLocaleData(localeDe);`

Comment: Thanks Nic that worked! A detailed explanation of your Angular5 solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564972/angular-5-breaking-change-manually-import-locale

Comment: The boolean value for "symbol" is marked as deprecated, here from doc: "Boolean (marked deprecated in v5): true for symbol and false for code."

Comment: Also add all imports needed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419026/missing-locale-data-for-the-locale-xxx-with-angular/48849230#48849230

import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr);

Comment: **IMP:-** If you used Currency Pipe in your LIbrary's souce code, then you have to registerLocaleData lang in your **Library Consuming Project's Module**, instead of your LIbrary's Module.

Answer (score 22):

This is working (angular 6)
on html side:

```
{{ amount | currency: 'EUR':'symbol':undefined:'fr-FR' }}
```

and on typescript side:

```
const number = 123456.789;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
```

123.456,79 €

Comment: Perfect solution! I would like to add minimumFractionDigits option: new Intl.NumberFormat(this.translateService.currentLang, {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'EUR',
          minimumFractionDigits: 0
        }).format(type.amount))

Answer (score 10):

I was looking to this answer, and the current version of angular it is possible to define providers for localization and Default currency code.

Like this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE } from '@angular/core';

import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

// Register the localization
registerLocaleData(localePt, 'pt-BR');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotificationListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'pt-BR'
     },
     {
       provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,
       useValue: 'BRL'
     },
    DataService,
    NotificationsService,
    GeoLocationService,
  ],
  entryComponents: components,
})
```

Once done, the utilization is very simple:

```
<div class="col-12" *ngIf="isContentInsurance.value">
     <h5 class="pull-left">Gst</h5>
     <span class="pull-right">-{{offers.contentInsurance | currency}}</span>
</div>
```

It is not necessary to create any custom pipeline or different custom action.

Answer (score 7):

For Angular12 you should import this in your module

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-DE', localeDeExtra);
```

And in your providers section

```
{
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'de-DE'
}
```

You can use like this

```
{{ price | currency:'EUR'}}
```

The result will be like this

```
    139,00 €
```

Comment: and you can  provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE and useValue: 'EUR' so you dont specify the currency symbol after the pipe

Comment: how to use Currency Pipe with Local in Angular LIbrary? I'm facing issue to use currency pipe with local in my library

Comment: **IMP:-** If you used Currency Pipe in your LIbrary's souce code, then you have to registerLocaleData lang in your **Library Consuming Project's Module**, instead of your LIbrary's Module.

Answer (score 3):

Provide LOCALE_ID was not a solution because my application is in english but shows the currency with french locale. So if I set my LOCALE_ID to `fr-FR`, all my dates are in french, which is not acceptable.

So I simply choose the [decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) then I add the symbol at the end.

```html
<div>
    {{ document.totalTaxAmount | number:'1.2-2' }} EUR
</div>
```

The problem here, if the number is not defined, you will end up with only the symbol. To resolve that issue, I've created a not empty pipe :

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'notEmpty'
})
export class NotEmptyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, replaceWith: any = ""): any {
        if (!value) {
            return replaceWith;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```html
<div>
    {{ document.totalTaxAmount | number:'1.2-2' | notEmpty: '0' }} EUR
</div>
```

Comment: I would put the `EUR` inside the transform method. looks good though.

Comment: this is not dynamic at all

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I couldn't find any in-built way to do it.
So created custom pipe called **split**.

**working Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/KX7hfaV2i7CX2VFobM8R?p=preview**

```
import{Component,provide,Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name:'split'})
export class ShiftPosition implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], value: string): string {
      return items.substr(1)+' ' +items.substr(0,1);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector:"my-app",

  template:`
    <h2>Dashboard<h2>
     {{price|currency:'EUR':true|split:price}}
  `
})

export class AppComponent{      
  price=10;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a bit of a hack. It seems that in the best case, using the locale as in @Maxim's answer is the right way to go since it will be formatted correctly according to the user's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't want to use 'fr' local, So :

```
import { PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import {CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';

    @Pipe({ name: 'myCurrency' })
    export class MyCurrencyPipe extends CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(value: any, currencyCode?: string, display?: 'code' | 'symbol' | 'symbol-narrow' | string | boolean, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string | null {
         let result = super.transform(value, currencyCode, display, digitsInfo, locale);
         if (result.charAt(0)==='₽' || result.charAt(0)==='$' ){
           result = result.substr(1)+' ' +result.substr(0,1);
         }else if(result.substr(0,3)==="TJS" || result.substr(0,3)==="RUB"){
           result = result.substr(3) +" "+result.substr(0,3)
         }
         if ( Number(value) >0 ){
           result = "+ "+ result
         }else{
           result = "- "+ result
         }
         return result;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own pipe to do this, also this is generalized also, it will automatically change the currency if the value in order.currency is different, unlike the hardcoded Currency

currency.pipe.ts

```
import { CurrencyPipe, getCurrencySymbol } from "@angular/common";
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name:'OmsCurrency'})
export class OmsCurrency implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() { }
  transform(value: string, curr: string): string {
    try {
      if (curr === "" || curr === null) {
        return value
      }
      else {
        return value + ' ' + getCurrencySymbol(curr,"narrow");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return value + ' ' + curr;
    }

  }
}
```

and in the html file just added the pipe

```
<div class="col-1 h5 text-right">
    {{( item.unitPrice ? item.unitPrice : "0.00" ) |  OmsCurrency: order.currency }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fix this problem for myself like the below

```
{{ product.price | currency: product.currency:"":".2-2" }} {{ orderInfo?.currency }}
```

Btw if I set if values of pipe in a normal way the output would be

```
{{ product.price | currency: product.currency:"symbol":".2-2" }}

TRY 45,666.00
```

But after customizing the pipe inputs the output is

```
{{ product.price | currency: product.currency:"":".2-2" }} {{ orderInfo?.currency }}

45,666.00 TRY
```

Answer (score 0):

To display currency in an Angular, we can leverage Angular's built-in pipe called currency. It formats a number as currency using the given locale and currency code.

app.module.ts

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US'}] //replace 'en-US' with your locale
```

html

```
{{ price | currency }}
```

Answer (score -3):

Do it like this:

```
{{price | currency:'EUR':true:'1.0-0'}}
```

No need for extra pipes, it uses the default currency pipe