# How to set align right/left in currency pipe angular2

Tags: angular, pipe

I am using currency pipe but does not know how to set align right/left. If Currency is a USD display right result but If I have the use INR display wrong result.

html:-

```
<div> {{amount | currency : 'USD' : true}} </div>
<div> {{amount | currency : 'INR' : true}} </div>
```

ts:-

```
amount = 100;
```

Output:-

```
$100
₹100
```

₹100 Output is wrong. The right output is 100₹. Please tell us how to set it. If any package for this please tell. I have searched many so I have to get currency masking.

Comment: You will have to customize the pipe, can you post a link of the pipe

Comment: This is default currency pipe. Please tell us how to possible its.

Comment: Are you sure that is right formatting?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee, If yes, then implement your own variant of CurrencyPipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format for indian rupees is:    ₹1, ₹2, ₹5, ₹10, etc.

To reproduce in this format, do the following:

**HTML**

```
 {{value | currency:'INR':true}}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

...
   @NgModule({
....    
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-IN' },
```

**Output**

> 34566666 will be shown as ₹ 3,45,66,666.00

**Notice**: indian formatting for thousands!

---

If you don't care about thousands formatting, then you can 'hack' (I am not sure if this is correct to do, but the result is good enough):

**app.module.ts**

providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-IN' }

**Output** would be

> 34 566 666,00 ₹

---

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-IN' }
```

Output would be

> 34.566.666,00 ₹

---

If all of this is not what you are looking for, then you should write a custom pipe.

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qO7ppRkz5YnxVA3TjZ1X?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

This post may help for  your case

[working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39634843/7261317)

can you try,i think we can't do in-built way to do it. So created custom pipe called split.