# Format long number to currency (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my Angular 2.0 app I get prices from webapi and i need to format them again for example :

This is what i get from webapi :  40260000  as a price and i need to format it to 40.260 HUF which is Hungarian currency.

I tried some solutions but it seems that i missed something for example :

```
 console.log(this.flatOffer.Price.toLocaleString('hu-HU'));
```

or

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hu-HU').format(this.flatOffer.Price));
```

I appreciate any hint.

Comment: Do you need format it to display in a view?

Comment: @alexmac yes exactly

Comment: Look closer at the [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) documentation. It has an options argument you need to use if you wish to format as currency.

Comment: Try to investigate [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe).

Comment: Currency is based on locale, see answers in this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634025/how-to-display-the-currency-symbol-to-the-right-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying the currency in a view, I would look into the [Angular Currency Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe).

Also look at the [Angular Decimal Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) to understand the second portion of formatting in the Currency Pipe.

You can pipe your expression similarily:

```
{{myCurrencyValue | currency:'HUF':false:'1.3-3'}}
```

Note: This may not be exactly what you want in terms of the decimal formatting, but it should give you a good idea as to how you can format the currency.

Comment: At the beginning i tried that one but what it shows is :  HUF20,130,000.000. and i also need to put HUF at the right side :P