# Missing locale data for the locale "XXX" with angular

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I currently define "*LOCALE_ID*" on "*en-US*" this way:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" }, ...],
    imports: [...],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
```

and it works pretty well. However, in order to test how dates look like in French, I replaced "*en-US*" by "*fr-FR*" and then I got the error:

> Missing locale data for the locale "fr-FR".

I did some researches and I didn't find anything related to that. Are the locale for french included in the default package? Is it a different package? Do I have to create them by myself?

Comment: https://next.angular.io/guide/i18n.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot, I saw that post but I missed the "i18n pipes" section. These articles are way too long. Thanks a lot, it works now ;-)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

In file `app.module.ts`

```
...
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr);


@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR'},
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

(source: https://next.angular.io/guide/i18n)

and in your template (`*.component.html`)

```
DATE in FRENCH: {{ dateEvent | date: 'longDate'}}
```

Result:

```
DATE in FRENCH: 25 mars 2018
```

(source: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: The `registerLocaleData(localeFr);` call is a pure side effect and will be stripped by tree shaking; In other words, if you enable tree-shaking with `"sideEffects": false` then this works in dev and fails in prod. Better to put it the function call into the AppModule constructor.

Comment: I had the same issue with this error message: Missing locale data for the locale "hu".' for pipe 'DatePipe'. This solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

Thanks @Alan, you just forgot this : `import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';`

Complete code :

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr);

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR'},
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent Angular versions, if you are using a single locale, you can just add it in your `angular.json` file under the project configuration like this:

```
"projects": {
  "disruptive-project": {
    "i18n": {
      "sourceLocale": "fr-FR"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also check in your `message.json` or any other file if your locale is correct:

[image]