# ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: "12-01-2020 - 12-02-2020' to a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, ecmascript-6

I am trying to concatenate two dates and assigning to variable but it is throwing an error
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert “12-01-2020 - 13-02-2020” into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'.where I am going wrong?

dates which I am getting from backend is projectStartDate: "2020-12-21T13:55:00.000+00:00".I am converting it to 12-01-2020 / timestamp after that concatenating both and assigning to projectduration value.

```
            this.startDate = this.datepipe.transform(response.projectStartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd','es-ES');
            this.endDate = this.datepipe.transform(response.projectEndDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd','es-ES');

            response.gbRFEbean.projectDuration.value = this.startDate + "-" +this.endDate ;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `response.projectStartDate` is just one date? Like `12-01-2020`

Comment: it is two dates after after concatenation.single date works fine

Comment: `projectStartDate: "2020-12-21T13:55:00.000+00:00". I am converting it to 12-01-2020 / timestamp` is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

**locale** is the fourth argument of the DatePipe transform and **timezone** is the third argument. Currently you have the locale as the third argument. I'd probably configure your locale like this (and the date pipe will automatically work for your locale without specifying):

[Missing locale data for the locale "XXX" with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419026/missing-locale-data-for-the-locale-xxx-with-angular/48849230)

transform takes either a javascript date or an ISO date string so I'm guessing your dates (projectStartDate, projectEndDate) are strings that aren't in the ISO format? The error message implies that one of those fields has the entire value of *12-01-2020 - 13-02-2020*

sample code with ISO date string

```
  startDate = '2020-01-12';
  endDate = '2020-02-13';

  formattedStartDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.startDate);
  formattedEndDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.endDate);

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    console.log(`${this.formattedStartDate} - ${this.formattedEndDate}`);
  }
```

Sample code with javascript date

```
  startDate = new Date('2020-01-12');
  endDate = new Date('2020-02-13');

  formattedStartDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  formattedEndDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    console.log(`${this.formattedStartDate} - ${this.formattedEndDate}`);
  }
```

If your dates are strings in a dd-MM-yyyy format, you can parse them with a library like luxon:

```
npm i luxon
```

And import

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
```

And parse

```
startDate = DateTime.fromFormat("12-01-2020", "dd-MM-yyyy").toISODate();
```

As a final note it's a little funny to put the dates in an ISO date format (yyyy-MM-dd) and then format them in the same format. The pipe makes more sense, particularly with you app locale set, if you want to use formats such as **mediumDate** (the default) which might display *12 ene. 2020*

Answer (score 0):

The Date format: **DD-MM-YYYY** is invalid.

You can try using :

```
new Date("12-01-2020")
```

It will give `Invalid Date` in chrome dev tools.

**Solution**

You can change the date format to **MM-DD-YYYY** and then pass it to `datepipe.transform`

```
let date = response.projectStartDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2-$1-$3")
this.startDate = this.datepipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd','es-ES');
date = response.projectEndDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2-$1-$3")
this.endDate = this.datepipe.transform(date , 'yyyy-MM-dd','es-ES');
```

Comment: I tried still getting this error .[FormsUI] Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "2020-12-21-2020-12-21" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'.Thing is projectduration field is not taking two dates .