# What is the meaning of error NG02100 in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

### Problem

Since some time we get an Error: NG02100 in our app. My problem is that I have no idea what is going and everything is working except one item in the navbar, but which has the identical code to the other components.

I tried checking the [docs](https://angular.io/errors), but the error is not documented there. Did anybody else have this error and can help out?

We use these Angular packages in our app for reference:

```
"@angular/animations": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/common": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/core": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/localize": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/router": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/service-worker": "^13.2.1",
"@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1302.2",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.2",
"@angular-devkit/core": "^13.2.2",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.2.2",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~1.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~1.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~1.0.0",
"@angular/cli": "^13.2.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.1",
"@angular/language-service": "^13.2.1",
```

Comment: is this the ng02100 you have ? => error: ng02100: invalidpipeargument: 'unable to convert "invalid date" into a date'

Comment: No, I also found the post describing this error. Unfortunately, it only says _ERROR Error: NG02100_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is something related to the `DatePipe` of Angular.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/606d94299ac929243e8fa10fe7e00dee6d40064b/goldens/public-api/common/errors.md

https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=INVALID_PIPE_ARGUMENT

[image: debug-screen]

This might be helpful as well.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20286

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Our problem was that a service returned an incorrect object which the component could not pass. That caused the error for us. So basically the component received `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

An `NG02100` error might also be masking an `NG0701` error which is a "missing locale data" error. You can confirm this using the **Developer Tools** of your browser, by putting a breakpoint in the `transform` call near the end of the stacktrace, and by running the offending line outside of its `try` block. If an `NG0701` error is raised, try one of these solutions:

- Either you forgot `--localize` in `ng build --localize`
- or you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419026/missing-locale-data-for-the-locale-xxx-with-angular) for other solutions

If this doesn't help, take another look at all the steps taken in the [Angular i18n docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview).

Answer (score 1):

`NG02100` means that one of Angular's built-in pipes was used with invalid arguments.

Generally, try to reproduce the error in dev mode, it will give you a proper stack trace and the name of the affected pipe.

In my case the problem was that I used the `async` pipe on a string:

```
{{ 'someString' | async }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used a number pipe on a string

```
{{someStr | number: '1.0-2'}} // Error: NG02100
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to extend pipe (`Extends DecimalPipe`) you will call `super()` with locale string name, for example:

```
super('en')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).