# Angular 5 Breaking change - manually import locale

Tags: angular

Changelog says:

> By default Angular now only contains locale data for the language
>   en-US, if you set the value of LOCALE_ID to another locale, you will
>   have to import new locale data for this language because we don’t use
>   the intl API anymore.

But I can not find any reference what "importing" means, how to do it and I get

> xxx.html:30 ERROR Error: Missing locale data for the
>   locale "de-CH"

I configure locale with :

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
```

and

```
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-CH' }
  ],
```

Comment: the only thing i can guess it Angular (v 5) is still in early RC the doc might update

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This is really hard to find in the current version :(. Here is what i found out:

The different locales are in the package `@angular/common/locales/`. In your case this is:

```
import localeDECH from '@angular/common/locales/de-CH';
```

Now you need to register this locale definitions in your project. There is a function called `registerLocaleData` that is located in: `@angular/common`.

So your code in your `app.module.ts` should look like this:

```
import {LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDECH from '@angular/common/locales/de-CH';

registerLocaleData(localeDECH);

@NgModule({
...
providers: [
   { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-ch' },
]
...
})
....
```

Comment: Effective! Thanks!

Comment: In angular 10 I get this warning app.module.ts depends on '@angular/common/locales/de'.
When using the 'localize' option this import is not needed. Did you mean to import '@angular/common/locales/global/de'?
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#import-global-variants-of-the-locale-data should i import from globals

Comment: Work. Then in the HTML template (example of use):  {{item?.myNumber| number:'':'de-CH'}}

Answer (score 23):

For

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' }
```

Use:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
registerLocaleData(localePt);
```

Comment: This really helps

Answer (score 4):

[Angular pipes can help you with internationalization: the DatePipe, CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe and PercentPipe use locale data to format data based on the LOCALE_ID.](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes)

By default, Angular only contains locale data for en-US. If you set the value of LOCALE_ID to another locale, you must import locale data for that new locale. The CLI imports the locale data for you when you use the parameter --locale with ng serve and ng build.

If you want to import locale data for other languages, you can do it manually:

```
src/app/app.module.ts
content_copy
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr);
```

The files in @angular/common/locales contain most of the locale data that you need, but some advanced formatting options might only be available in the extra dataset that you can import from @angular/common/locales/extra. An error message informs you when this is the case.

```
src/app/app.module.ts
content_copy
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFrCa from '@angular/common/locales/fr-CA';
import localeFrCaExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr-CA';

registerLocaleData(localeFrCa, localeFrCaExtra);
```

See the table about old and new locale too
[image]