# Angular Locale settings not working

Tags: angular

I want to customize my Angular app locale to 'en-GB' and did as the answer here suggests: [Angular 5 Breaking change - manually import locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564972/angular-5-breaking-change-manually-import-locale)

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeGB from '@angular/common/locales/en-GB';

registerLocaleData(localeGB, 'en-GB');

...

providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GB' }]
```

But this didn't fix my issue and the currency pipe outputs $ instead of £.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass `currencyCode` to display `£` because default is undefined and it display `$`. Use it as:

```
<span>{{amount | currency:'GBP'}}</span>
```

> there is no relation between locale & currency code, locale generally used for format of different things (like number) i.e. how it would be displayed in particular locale. E.g. at some places `,` is being used at the place of `.` (decimal); or what should be the thousand separator.

Comment: How can I pass 'GBP' as a variable? Say in the component.ts: `currencyCode = 'GBP'` and then in the HTML have something like `<span>{{amount | currency:currencyCode}}</span>`