# How to identify the current set "locale"

Tags: angular

I know how to set the locale for my angular app. It´s needed for example to use the DatePipe. Is there any possibility to read/get the current locale from the app?

To set the locale is use the following imports and methods:

```
import { default as localeDe } from '@angular/common/locales/de';
[...]
registerLocaleData(localeDe);
```

But I cannot find any solution, the get information about the previously set locale, or, if any locales have been registered before.

Side node:
Its clear how to get the current locale of the client/browser, thats not the point. Its just about the set locales inside the app itself.

I expect to read the locale out of the current app state to decide programmatically if I need to set the locale using "registerLocaleData".

Answer (score 2):

I'm still trying to get a hang of Angular myself, but you could try the following:

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733006/9552551).
It says, you should also set a provider in your app module:

```
providers: [
   { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de' },
]
```

Then you can inject `LOCALE_ID` in your constructor wherever you want to use it:

```
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}
```

There is some info about LOCALE_ID in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID).