# Angular - bind different values to view and model

Tags: angular, input, data-binding, formatting

I have an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myValue" [ngModel]="richiesta.myValue" 
formControlName="myValue" (change)="onValueChange($event.target.value)">
```

The input is for currency, so I want the user to be able to write 12345 (number) and the field should be formatted like this: 12.345,00 € (string)
My problem is that I want to preserve the original inputted number to be saved to the database.
Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

**EDIT**
After @ConnorsFan answer I edited my code but it's still not working, the value is not formatted. Am I missing some import? Here's my code.
*view*

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myValue" [ngModel]="richiesta.myValue | currency:'EUR':true" formControlName="myValue"
(change)="onValueChange($event.target.value)">
```

*component*

```
onValueChange(e){
    console.log(e)
    console.log(this.richiesta.value.myValue)
  }
```

*app.module*

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
...
providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT'}]
```

**EDIT2**
I was looking for a solution to my problem and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular2-view) similar to mine. I used the approach suggested by the accepted answer, and now my view looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="myValue" 
(ngModelChange)="richiesta.myValue = $event" 
[ngModel]="richiesta.myValue | currency:'EUR':true"
formControlName="myValue"
placeholder="Importo Finanziamento (€)" (change)="onValueChange($event.target.value)">
```

The pipe seems to work, but the `ngModelChange` triggers at every digit inputted. So if I type 12345 I get 1,00 €2345 and the consequential error: `InvalidPipeArgument: '1,00 €2345' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'`. Is there a way to solve this kind of side effect?

Comment: add your component code for onValueChange($event.target.value) event handler

Answer (score 1):

You can format the value in the field with the [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe):

```
[ngModel]="richiesta.myValue | currency:'EUR':true"       (for Angular 2 and 4)
[ngModel]="richiesta.myValue | currency:'EUR':'symbol'"   (for Angular 5)
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293794/1009922) from Benedikt, a locale may also be specified. You can save the numeric value to your database as you want in `onValueChange`.

[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iTc0g9WtIhmt7k9qVMsu?p=preview) shows how it can be done for Angular 4.2.4, using the following code:

```
import { Component, NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Angular 4 - Currency formatting</h1>
  <input [ngModel]="amount | currency:'EUR':true" (change)="onValueChange($event.target.value)" name="inputField" type="text" />
  `
})
export class App { 
  public amount: number = 1234;

  public onValueChange(value): void {
    this.amount = value;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT' }],  
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm afraid this works only inside the double curly brackets.

Comment: According to my tests (see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iTc0g9WtIhmt7k9qVMsu?p=preview)), it works also with `ngModel`.

Comment: Hi @ConnorsFan, I updated my code. Your solution is fine but doesn't work for me, while it works perfecly if I do something like {{richiesta.myValue | currency:'EUR':true}}.

Comment: What version of Angular are you working with? Do you see any error in the console when loading the application?

Comment: I just posted another edit. I'm using angular 4.2.4 and in the code of my first edit I don't see any error.

Comment: Make sure that you import the `CommonModule` and that you add it to the `imports` list of the `AppModule`, as shown in the `app.ts` file of my plunker. My solution should work for you like it does in the plunker.

Comment: I changed the version of my plunker to Angular 4.2.4, and the locale to it-IT.

Comment: I added the CommonModule that was missing, but still nothing. I'm starting to think that there's something in my app that prevents this kind of behaviour...